# WPF - Stackpanel won't wrap

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a stackpanel that I dynamically add 50x50 rectangles to. I want it display 6 in per line and automatically add a line as it approaches the threshold per. (i.e. 12 rectangles == 2 lines.) I can't seem to get it to properly wrap though. here's my XAML code (I've cut off the stuff in the other rows as I suspect they are not relevant):

```
 <Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="230"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Swatch Thumbnails</TextBlock>
      <StackPanel x:Name="sp_Thumbnails" Width="300" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,15,0,0">
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
            <TextBlock.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
            </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
              <TextBlock.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
               </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
                <TextBlock.Background>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
                </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
                <TextBlock.Background>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
                  </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
             <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
              <TextBlock.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
                 </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,4,0" >
            <TextBlock.Background>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
         </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `UniformGrid` and set its `Columns` property to 6?

Comment: Not sure what that does?

Comment: There is online documentation. Read it.

Comment: I was, however that is very unhelpful. :/

Comment: @Clemens Alright, I got the uniformGrid working. If you post as an answer I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UniformGrid` and set its `Columns` property to 6:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="6">
    ...            
</UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WrapPanel instead of StackPanel

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't appear to work either.